# How to make menu ul roll new every 5s?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a list of new like this:

```
<ul>
  <li><a>new1</a></li>
  <li><a>new2</a></li>
  <li><a>new3</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want the `ul` only show a new and then  that new will move up and and disappear. In next 5s, another new move up and disappear. When the last one disappear the  first one would take place again.
I don't know how setup it with jquery/javascript.

Comment: look up the following JS methods: document.createElement(), .appendChild(), window.setInterval() and document.getElementById() and .remove()

Comment: Thank a lot. I will try. And happy New Year ^^.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can try this:

**Html:**

```
<ul id="marquee"> 
 <li><a>new1</a></li>
  <li><a>new2</a></li>
  <li><a>new3</a></li>
</ul>
```

**jquery**

```
window.setInterval(function () {
    var updated = $("#marquee li:first-child");
    $.unique(updated).each(function(i) {
      $(this).slideUp(function() {
        $(this).appendTo(this.parentNode).slideDown();
      });
    });
}, 5000);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mSmbv/1254/

Comment: Nice. This's really what i am trying to do with JQuery.  But i will only let user see a new  per turn.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use jQuery to achieve this please find the following [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bhatnagar018/ez9mhvxp/).

```
<div id="container">
</div>

<button onclick="start()">
  Start/Stop
</button>


var i = 0,
  id = null;

function start() {
  if (id == null) {
    id = setInterval(prepareDom, 5000)

    function prepareDom() {
      jQuery("<ul><li>" + (i++) + "</li><li>" + (i++) + "</li></ul>").appendTo("#container");
    }
  } else {
    window.clearInterval(id);
    id = null;
  }
}
```